# Styles are not visible in dev-tools panel

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, protocols

I'm trying to display element styles for node with `nodeId` using **devtools-protocol**

When element is hovered and clicked I receive 4 messages in total

- CSS.getMatchedStylesForNode
- CSS.getComputedStyleForNode
- CSS.getPlatformFontsForNode
- CSS.getPlatformFontsForNode

to which I respond (I think) correctly, yet styles are not visible in dev-tools panel

[image: Screenshot of dev-tools styles panel]

Detailed communication:

Requests:

- `{"id":35,"method":"CSS.getMatchedStylesForNode","params":{"nodeId":80}}`
- `{"id":36,"method":"CSS.getComputedStyleForNode","params":{"nodeId":80}}`
- `{"id":37,"method":"CSS.getPlatformFontsForNode","params":{"nodeId":80}}`
- `{"id":38,"method":"CSS.getInlineStylesForNode","params":{"nodeId":80}}`

Responses. (Were too long, so I shorted them, CONTENT is a placeholder for their content)

- `{"result":{"cssKeyframesRules":[],"inherited":[{ CONTENT }],"id":35}`
- `{"result":{"computedStyle":[{ CONTENT }],"id":36}`
- `{"result":{"fonts":[]},"id":37}`
- `{"result":{"inlineStyle":{"cssProperties":[],"cssText":"","range":{"endColumn":0,"endLine":0,"startColumn":0,"startLine":0},"shorthandEntries":[],"styleSheetId":"69061.90"}},"id":38}`

I would love to hear any pointer in the direction of a solution.

Comment: I'm not aware of posting an image of either code or an error. The image i s present purely to illustrate state of the dev-tools panel.

Comment: The image is not a pillar of the specification and can be removed without the post losing context. As I said, it's purely to *illustrate* the state of the dev-tools panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Chromium [CSSRule.js](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/sdk/CSSRule.js?type=cs&q=CSSRule&sq=package:chromium&l=39).

> If the payload you report in getMatchedStyles includes styleSheetId's,
>   then you should also report the stylesheet with this id to the
>   front-end. You should emit the CSS.styleSheetAdded event for that.

Answer (score -1):

Try this from [Google Chrome Dev Tools inspect element styles not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27232534/google-chrome-dev-tools-inspect-element-styles-not-showing).

> I just had this same issue and to resolve it I went into Chrome
>   Developer Tools -> Settings -> Scroll to the bottom and click "Restore
>   defaults and reload" then it all magically came back!
>
> I hadn't changed anything between it working and when it stopped so
>   not sure why it broke but hopefully this helps you too.

If that doesn't work, try reinstalling your Chrome web browser.