# Chrome inspect element not showing

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have a really weird condition about my chrome browser, the inspect element not showing at all after i right click and i choose "Inspect" and even after i use the shortcut key "Ctrl+Shift+I" it still not showing, what is really happened ?

I have checked "chrome://flags/" and "Debugging for packed apps" and it show me "Enabled" what is really going on with my chrome browser ? i use chrome "68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)".

I have followed some instruction from another web but still the "Inspect" window not showing.

Here some links that i have followed to solve this problem.

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-resolve-the-issue-in-Chrome-for-inspect-element-if-its-not-showing-up-for-any-website

[Google Chrome Dev Tools inspect element styles not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27232534/google-chrome-dev-tools-inspect-element-styles-not-showing)

Please Help.

Comment: Version 69.x is out now. Try updating. Barring that try removing it entirely and reinstalling. If those don't work, try chrome canary until the problem is resolved.

Comment: can you please post some screen shot of what you are seeing ?

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, i have solved this problem by uninstall chrome completely and than reinstall chrome.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was the only solution on Mac OS X:

1. Quit Chrome then delete /Applications/Google Chrome.app.
2. Delete these folders: 
   ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome
   ~/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Default
3. Re-install Google Chrome

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, i have solved this problem by uninstall chrome completely and than reinstall chrome.

Answer (score -1):

resolve the issue with the Inspect Element feature in Chrome browser, it's probably due to a specific problem with your Chrome installation or system configuration. In this case, you can try reinstalling Chrome for a fresh installation. Another option is to seek further assistance by posting your problem on the Chrome support forums or contacting Google support directly. They have the expertise to provide specific guidance for your particular situation.

Here is the link to the Chrome Help Forum: https://support.google.com/chrome/community

Comment: is this edited chatgpt?

Comment: No , this is my opinion.